# How to find a consecutive sequence of symbols in a squared matrix

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need help finding the right algorithm. I have a 2d array, for example:

```
var arr = [
[""," "," "," ",""],
[""," "," "," ",""],
[""," "," ","X",""],
["","X","X","X",""],
[""," "," ","X",""]];
```

And I want to verify if this array has three next symbols that match each other in any direction (horizontal or vertical, or cross), then display this symbols.

I'm doing it like this:

Run through array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1){
   for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j+=1){
```

Then verify if match:

```
if(arr[i][j] == "X" && arr[i+1][j] == "X" && arr[i+2][j] == "X"){

       console.log(arr[i][j]);
```

But it will give an error, because `i+1` and `i+2` are behind the array.

I've tried to make verification if:

```
  if(arr[i][j+1] < arr.length)
```

But it doesn't count the last rows.

How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried to do `if(arr[i][j+1] <= arr.length)`?

Comment: Looking at the contents of the array(`arr[i][j+1]`) to determine if you are in bounds or not doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to count successive for each row, column or diagonal.

#### Given a step function that count successive "X"

```
data = {
    succX = 0
};

function step (data, arr, i, j) {
    data.succX = arr[i][j] === "X" ? data.succX + 1 : 0;
    return data.succX >= 3;;
}
```

Then, you can iterate and look for step result. If step return `true`, we might store the corresponding sequence and stop searching.

#### Iterate over each row

```
for (var i = 0, nbRow = arr.length; i < nbRow; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, nbCol = arr[i].length; j < nbCol; j++) {
        data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i, j-2], [i, j-1], [i, j]];
    }
}

data.succX = 0;
```

#### Iterate over each column

```
for (var j = 0, nbCol = arr[0].length; j < nbCol; j++) {
    for (var i = 0, nbRow = arr.length; i < nbRow; i++) {
        data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i-2, j], [i-1, j], [i, j]];
    }
}
```

#### Iterate over each diagonal

```
for (var d = 0, dim = arr.length, nbDiag = dim * 2 - 1; d < nbDiag; d++) {
    var maxE = d >= dim ? nbDiag - d - 1 : d;
    for (var e = 0; e <= maxE; e++) {
        var i = Math.min(d, dim -1) - e,
            j = Math.max(0, d - dim + 1) + e;
        data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i, j-2], [i+1, j-1], [i+2, j]];
    }
    data.succX = 0;
}

for (var d = 0, dim = arr.length, nbDiag = dim * 2 - 1; d < nbDiag; d++) {
    var maxE = d >= dim ? nbDiag - d - 1 : d;
    for (var e = 0; e <= maxE; e++) {
        var i = dim - 1 -Math.min(d, dim -1) + e,
            j = Math.max(0, d - dim + 1) + e;
        data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i-2, j-2], [i-1, j-1], [i, j]];
    }
    data.succX = 0;
}
```

At the end, `data.winSeq` contains either undefined or a valid sequence.

You can see the whole process illustrated in the snippet right below.

```js
var delay = 0;

function findWinSeq(arr, seqLength) {
    var data = { succX: 0 };

    // Iteration step
    function step (data, arr, i, j) {

        if (arr[i][j] === "X") {
            data.succX++;
            colorize(i, j, "validCell", delay);
        } else {
            data.succX = 0;
            colorize(i, j, "selectCell", delay);
        }

        var hasWon = data.succX >= seqLength;
        delay += hasWon ? 2000 : 120;

        return hasWon;
    }

    // Count for each row
    for (var i = 0, nbRow = arr.length; i < nbRow; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, nbCol = arr[i].length; j < nbCol; j++) {
            data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i, j-2], [i, j-1], [i, j]];
        }
    }

    data.succX = 0;

    // Count for each column
    for (var j = 0, nbCol = arr[0].length; j < nbCol; j++) {
        for (var i = 0, nbRow = arr.length; i < nbRow; i++) {
            data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i-2, j], [i-1, j], [i, j]];
        }
    }

    // Count for each diagonal
    for (var d = 0, dim = arr.length, nbDiag = dim * 2 - 1; d < nbDiag; d++) {
        var maxE = d >= dim ? nbDiag - d - 1 : d;
        for (var e = 0; e <= maxE; e++) {
            var i = Math.min(d, dim -1) - e,
                j = Math.max(0, d - dim + 1) + e;
            data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i, j-2], [i+1, j-1], [i+2, j]];
        }
        data.succX = 0;
    }

    for (var d = 0, dim = arr.length, nbDiag = dim * 2 - 1; d < nbDiag; d++) {
        var maxE = d >= dim ? nbDiag - d - 1 : d;
        for (var e = 0; e <= maxE; e++) {
            var i = dim - 1 -Math.min(d, dim -1) + e,
                j = Math.max(0, d - dim + 1) + e;
            data.winSeq = data.winSeq || step(data, arr, i, j) && [[i-2, j-2], [i-1, j-1], [i, j]];
        }
        data.succX = 0;
    }

    return data.winSeq || null;
}


var tests = [
[

[" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" ","X"," ","X"," "],
    [" "," ","X"," "," "],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" ","X"," "," "," "]
    ],
    [

    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" ","X"," ","X"," "],
    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" ","X"," "," "," "]
    ],
    [

    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" ","X"," ","X"," "],
    [" "," "," "," ","X"],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" ","X","X"," "," "]
    ],
    [

    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" "," ","X","X"," "],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" ","X"," "," "," "]
    ],
    [

    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    ["X","X","X","X"," "],
    [" "," ","X"," "," "],
    [" "," "," ","X"," "],
    [" ","X"," "," "," "]
    ],
    ];

// Just some fancy stuffs
function colorize(i, j, color, delay) {
    function _colorize(i, j, color) {

        // Reset first valid cell if needed
        if (color === "selectCell") {
            var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("validCell");
            for(var k = 0, cell; cell = cells[k]; k++) {
                cell.className = "cell";
            }
        }

        // Apply color to the next cell
        var previous = document.getElementsByClassName("selectCell")[0];
        if (previous !== undefined) { previous.className = "cell"; }
        document.getElementById([i,j].join("")).className = color;
    }
    setTimeout(_colorize, delay, i, j, color);
}

function buildBoard (test) {
    var board = document.getElementById("board");
    board.style.width = test.length * 40 + "px";
    board.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0, marker, cell, dim = test.length; i < dim; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.className = "cell";
            cell.id = [i,j].join("");
            if (test[i][j] === "X") {
                marker = document.createElement('div');
                marker.className = "marker";
                cell.appendChild(marker);
            }
            board.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0, test; test = tests[i]; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (test) {
        setTimeout(function (test) {
            buildBoard(test);
        }, delay, test);
        findWinSeq(test, 3);
    }, 750 * i, test);
}
```

```css
#board {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.cell, .validCell, .selectCell {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.validCell {
    background: #CDEB8B;
}

.selectCell {
    background: #DDD;
}

.marker {
    background: #888;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 12px 0 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for your answer, I hope it will help, anyway I'm sure I will learn some useful moves from this. Very very thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops should stop when `i < arr.length-2`, because you want to be sure that `i+2` is within bounds.

Comment: But then it wouldn't find vertical arrangements in the last columns, or horizontal ones in the last rows.

Comment: But then I won't run through the all array. It's works as the my last rule:  if(arr[i][j+1] < arr.length)

Comment: This answer assumes the body of the loop doesn't change; if you want to access `arr[i+2][j]`, you'd better be sure `i < arr. length-2` (so that `i+2 < arr. length`).

Answer (score 0):

Three consecutive X symbols are uniquely defined by their center and the direction (horizontal, vertical or one of two diagonals). I'd do it like this (thanks @DarthJS):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j+=1) {
        // Horizontal
        if (i > 0 && i < arr.length - 1 &&
            arr[i-1][j] == "X" && arr[i][j] == "X" && arr[i+1][j] == "X") {
            console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
        // Vertical
        if (j > 0 && j < arr.length - 1 &&
            arr[i][j-1] == "X" && arr[i][j] == "X" && arr[i][j+1] == "X") {
            console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
        // Diagonal
        if (i > 0 && i < arr.length - 1 &&
            j > 0 && j < arr.length - 1) {
            if (arr[i-1][j-1] == "X" && arr[i][j] == "X" && arr[i+1][j+1] == "X") {
                console.log(arr[i][j]);
            }
            if (arr[i-1][j+1] == "X" && arr[i][j] == "X" && arr[i+1][j-1] == "X") {
                console.log(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not verify the last row

Comment: Wait, your loops begin from i=0 and j=0, but all cases validate only when i>0 and j>0. Any conflicts?

Comment: No, when i = 0 the 'vertical' part is still checked. And for j=0 the 'horizontal' part.